# How to decrypt database value and show it in view in Laravel 5

Tags: php, encryption, laravel-5

I have used

```
php artisan key:generate
```

command to generate API_KEY and then used **encrypt()** function to save passport number in database. I would like my logged in customers to be shown the decrypted passport number when they try to view data. How do I decrypt it in view? I have tried:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('quest_passport_number', 'Passport number') !!}
        {!! Form::text('quest_passport_number', decrypt($reservation->guest_passport_number)) !!}
    </div>
```

I get **The payload is invalid.** How to get this value? Do I need to add a function to model, or to controller or something?

Comment: Have you checked that `$reservation->guest_passport_number` contains exactly what you think it should contain?

Comment: Yes @KIKOSoftware, it contains the value saved in database and if I leave out the function decrypt(), it shows that.

eyJpdiI6InVER3JqS0hQMGRwSUFBcEhpNlJxMkE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiTExqa1lyVkdkdEtKeXRwbWcyYVYzZz09IiwibWFjIjoiMGMzMzFjODRhNzUwM2NhZWY2NjU3YjY3YzU4Yjc0NGJjYTkxM2RkZDM3MTdlYzU5NWVjOTJmOWE3MGJjNzE2NSJ9

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/decrypt-the-payload-is-invalid

Comment: @Sohel0415 I've come across this, but I don't see how it's different from what I'm doing. $reservation->guest_passport_number is my encrypted value.

Comment: it would be better if you could share your controller code.

Comment: @Sohel0415 here is my controller: [link](https://codeshare.io/GkK6BY)

Comment: I am so sorry, I had a spelling error here. I've used G instead of Q (I've spelled it right but my spelling in database is wrong). So this code is OK, and @KIKOSoftware has pointed me in the right direction. Laravel prints the correct value without decrypt anyway because it's smart and does so even when you put null. Sorry for the confusion.